# Positioned elements not showing correctly on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I am writing a script for a meme i'm doing for a client.

I have text boxes which I use to get content and then display it on the meme image using javascript.

The texts show and displays correctly on desktop and mobile landscape view, but on portrait view, the positions just don't appear correctly.

```
                        <div class="col-md-3">

                            <div>
                                <div class="input-group mrg30T">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control bdr md2" placeholder="Enter Your First Name" maxlength="12" id="custom_name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your first name">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <div class="input-group mrg10T">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control bdr md2" placeholder="Profession / Industry" maxlength="22" id="industry" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your profession">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <div class="input-group mrg10T">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control bdr md2" placeholder=" Phone No / Email" maxlength="45" id="contact" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email / phone no.">
                                </div>
                            </div>  

    <div class="example" style="position: relative;">
        <!-- cropper container element -->
        <div class="default"></div>

    <div style="position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; height:100%; width:100%;" class="template-overlay">
        <img src="" class="overlay" style="width:100%;height:94.2%;">
                                    </div>

    <div id="html-content-holder" style="position: relative;">

<div style="position:absolute;  top: -295px;  left: 120px; right: 122px"     class="text-overlay">
<label class="label_over" id="dummy_label" style=" text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 40px; font-family: 'BebasNeue'" >  </label>
                                    </div>

<div style="position:absolute;  top: -50px;  left: 118px; right: 122px" class="text-overlay">
<label class="label_over" id="industry_label" style=" text-transform: capitalize; letter-spacing: -0.7px; font-size: 15px; font-family: montserrat; font-weight: 400" >  </label>
                                    </div>

<div style="position:absolute;  top: -35px;  left: 50px; right: 50px" class="text-overlay">
<label class="label_over" id="contact_label" style=" text-transform: lowercase; letter-spacing: -0.5px; font-size: 14px; font-family: montserrat; font-weight: 400" >  </label>
                                    </div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
```

so it looks like this after the user is done [final image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6IVP.png)

The live site can be seen here http://meme.openforbusiness.ng/

P.S: It works well on desktop and mobile landscape view, I need a fix for the "mobile portrait view"

Comment: honestly it works really good i do not see any issue in "mobile portrait view"

Comment: @felixsturm it's not even showing the texts on my device, I use chrome browser on an android phone.

Comment: May I suggest you get rid of the `position:absolute;`, as that will just create trouble in the long run, and is most likely the issue in this case as well. Learn how to position without absolute positioning

Comment: @LGSon I understand how that may be an issue, but it doesn't help me solve this problem, like I said I have tried all I know.